# linux shell scripting replacing value after specific delimiter using sed

Tags: ubuntu, sed

i have this :

```
sed -e "/$name/s/[0-9]\:*$/$P/" -i sales_info.txt
```

When i use the above to change this : My text file format **name:no:no:type:p**

```
Tom:8:987654:commission:0
Tommy:7:12379813:hourly:0
Fan:5:2132131:salaried:0
```

assuming $name = Tom , $P = 55.5

i get this :

```
Tom:8:987654:commission:0
Tommy:7:12379813:hourly:55.5
Fan:5:2132131:salaried:0
```

However if i try to change the $P from 55.5 to 41.5

it becomes

```
Tom:8:987654:commission:0
Tommy:7:12379813:hourly:55.41.5
Fan:5:2132131:salaried:0
```

I have tried :

```
sed -e "/$name/s/\:[0-9]*$/\:$P/" -i sales_info.txt
```

It only changes the value from `:0`
 If the value is more than 0 , it won't change at all.
Assuming if i would insist to use sed for this . have i place the `:` in the wrong position ? Im trying to change the last column value after `:`

Comment: AFAIK `:` doesn't need to be escaped here. However since `.` isn't in the range `[0-9]`, the pattern `[0-9]*` won't match decimals like `55.5` - you'd need something like `[0-9.]*` i.e. `"/$name/s/:[0-9.]*$/:$P/"`

Comment: hi , actually i tried the . too , it removed everything except the name which means **name:no:no:type:p** to **name:p** @steeldriver

Comment: Are you sure you put the `.` **inside** the brackets i.e. `[0-9.]*` not outside like `[0-9].*`?

Comment: thanks it work . would like u to answer so i could accept it

Comment: Note that you should also match name to word boundaries, e.g. `/\b$name\b/`

Comment: or `/^$name:/`... also if you are not worried about contents of last column, you can use `s/[^:]*$/$P/`

Answer (score 0):

[Answered in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320949/linux-shell-scripting-replacing-value-after-specific-delimiter-using-sed#comment564238_320949):

> AFAIK : doesn't need to be escaped here. However since . isn't in the range [0-9], the pattern [0-9]* won't match decimals like 55.5 - you'd need something like [0-9.]* i.e. "/$name/s/:[0-9.]*$/:$P/"